# How do I make a link to any province in Iraq map (iraq.js) to an html page, I downloaded from https://jsmaps.io/asia/javascript-map-of-iraq/

Tags: javascript

```
window.JSMaps.maps.iraq = {
    "config": {
        "mapWidth": 799.52,
        "mapHeight": 813.2,
        "defaultText": "<h1>Iraq</h1><br /><p>Iraq,  MOC, ITPC .</p><p> Planning Dept.</p>"
    },
    "paths": [
        {
            "enable": true,
            "name": "بابل",
            "abbreviation": "بابل",
            "textX": 478,
            "textY": 483,
            "color": "#59798e",
            "hoverColor": "#E32F02",
            "selectedColor": "#feb41c",
            "url": "http://jsmaps.io",
            "text": "<h1>Babil بابل</h1><br /><p>123</p>",
            "path": "M445.01,424.36L443.22,423.81L438,420.71L435.97,420.1L434,419.82L426.23,419.77L419,417.85L415.3,417.36L412.53,417.74L412.94,419.8L414.03,421.17L418.06,422.17L426,426.19L428.49,428.69L430.45,434.47L431.9,441.77L432.91,444.39L435.15,446.95L438.71,449.44L437.79,458.68L440.05,459.02L442.9,459.8L443.33,459.86L443.71,459.8L444.59,459.31L445.02,459.13L445.4,459.11L445.9,459.31L446.46,459.73L448.44,461.75L448.77,462.52L448.79,463.09L448.84,464.19L448.08,465L445.2,475.52L445.38,479.15L446.73,482.44L451.33,489.19L451.91,491.13L451.13,493.06L450.73,494.65L451.33,496.67L453.03,500.02L453.29,501.07L454.45,505.7L455.01,506.62L455.51,507.13L455.18,508.79L453.21,509.9L452.61,510.88L452.74,511.93L453.38,513.72L454.93,516.21L455.46,516.83L456.07,517.77L456.47,518.59L457.71,520.25L460.62,517.47L462.31,516.31L462.69,516.33L463.36,516.19L463.99,516.26L468.01,513.37L470.24,514.56L472.06,516.1L474.49,517.5L478.64,518.86L481.09,519.64L485.61,522.39L486.67,522.79L487.65,522.78L488.42,522.52L489.1,522.14L489.65,521.63L491.22,519.69L491.7,519.3L492.93,518.56L493.37,518.2L493.72,517.67L493.78,516.96L493.67,516.08L493.02,515.49L492.66,515.08L492.53,514.63L492.76,513.96L493.24,513.11L494.03,512.26L494.63,511.98L495.12,512.03L495.59,512.42L496.52,513.37L497.03,513.62L497.58,513.3L499.98,511.03L503.56,508.28L508.81,506.13L515.83,501.43L516.39,500.91L517.38,499.69L518.36,498.96L522.01,496.74L523.16,496.29L523.87,496.1L525.06,496.16L524.93,494.15L524.7,491.12L523.65,491.1L518.77,490.88L517.4,490.49L516.08,489.57L514.51,487.99L513.09,486.18L509.9,478.97L506.4,467.35L505.9,466.3L504.79,465.08L503.63,464.15L501.53,462.96L498.88,461.83L498.44,461.09L497.74,460.85L494.76,460.57L490.63,459.26L485.44,456.28L484.88,456.14L473.32,455.32L472.82,455.13L472.43,454.83L471.87,454.3L471.33,452.76L470.83,450.36L470.55,440.5L469.94,437.6L471.3,436.82L471.78,435.46L471.82,431.67L471.51,429.61L470.87,427.21L469.41,423.47L468.39,421.4L468.43,420.25L468.42,420.25L454.87,419.56L452.78,418.97L451.73,418.8L450.66,418.96L448.22,422.4L446.73,423.87L445.01,424.36z"
        },
```

Comment: please explain more for help i can't understand your problem at all

Comment: I want to make link to html page when cursor point to province .... thanks